# Как запустить метод в заданное время?

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Доброго времени суток) Пишу приложение, которое будет менять громкость в заданное время. Есть TimePickerDialog, выбранные значения которых заносятся в переменные.
И есть также выбранная громкость, которая заносится в нужную переменную. Сделал AlarmManager, который почему-то не срабатывает вовсе, даже если не указывать нужные переменные. Я чайник! Помогите! Что я делаю не так?
Первый класс

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // finals
    final TextView editTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTime);
    final TextView editVolume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editVolume);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    // Users clicks
    // set Time
    editTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    String selectedMinute0;
                    if (selectedMinute == 0 || selectedMinute == 1 || selectedMinute == 2 || selectedMinute == 3 || selectedMinute == 4 || selectedMinute == 5 || selectedMinute == 6 || selectedMinute == 7 || selectedMinute == 8 || selectedMinute == 9) {
                        selectedMinute0 = "0";
                        editTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute0 + selectedMinute);
                        checktime = true;
                    } else {
                        editTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        checktime = true;
                    }
                    time_set_h = selectedHour;
                    time_set_m = selectedMinute;
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
            timepickerdialog.show();
        }
    });
    // set Volume level
    editVolume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder volumeSetter = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            volumeSetter.setTitle(R.string.ChangeVolume);
            volumeBar = new SeekBar(MainActivity.this);
            volumesetter = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeBar.setMax(volumesetter.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
            volumeBar.setProgress(volumesetter.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
            volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    volume = progress;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }
            });
            volumeSetter.setView(volumeBar);
            volumeSetter.setNeutralButton(R.string.OkeyButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    editVolume.setText(getString(R.string.Set) + volume);
                    volume_set = volume;
                    checkvolume = true;
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            volumeSetter.setNegativeButton(R.string.Back_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            volumeSetter.show();
        }
    });
    // main button
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder button_alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            if (!checktime) {
                button_alert.setMessage(R.string.DidnotSetTime);
                button_alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.Back_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            } else if (!checkvolume) {
                button_alert.setMessage(R.string.DidnotSetVolumeLevel);
                button_alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.Back_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                button_alert.setMessage(R.string.CompleteText);
                button_alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.OkeyButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        AM();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                button_alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.Back_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            }
            button_alert.show();
        }
    });
}

public void AM() {
    MyBroadcast al = new MyBroadcast();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        al.SetAlarm(this, pi);
}
```

и второй

```
AudioManager volumesetter;



public void SetAlarm(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
    Calendar c_time = Calendar.getInstance();
    c_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
    c_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c_time.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    volumesetter.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
    volumesetter.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 3, 3);
    volumesetter.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
    volumesetter.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 3, 3);
    volumesetter.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    volumesetter.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 3, 3);
}
```